# Ability to filter for questions on hold?

Tags: discussion

An offshoot of my earlier question (Hold process suggestion):  it seems that it would be a service for willing members to go through questions in the hold queue and try to edit them to solve whatever the issue is if the question is fixable (including leaving comments requesting specific information if needed).  It appears that reviewers have access to the queue, itself.  I'm wondering if there is some type of filter so that any user (or users above a certain rep), can see the questions on hold, aggregated.  There are an awful lot of questions and just scrolling through page after page looking for ones on hold is not very efficient.  I have no idea how big the queue is.  If there aren't that many questions in it, this probably isn't worthwhile.

Comment: Is searching for `closed:1 is:q` what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This search](https://superuser.com/search?tab=active&q=closed%3a1%20is%3aq%20duplicate%3a0%20migrated%3a0) looks like what you want... It finds:

- Questions which are not marked as duplicate
- Questions which have not been migrated to another site
- Questions which are "on hold" or closed
- Sorts the results by most recent activity on the question
- Excludes answers

To see what search parameters there are, do a search (on any StackExchange site or meta-site) and click "Advanced search tips" on the right hand side. Or go [here](https://superuser.com/help/searching).

Comment: Thanks.  That gets it from 240,000 to 9,000.  Should be a lot of meat there.  Any way to specify a time frame? (fixing many of the problems requires input from the poster so ancient questions are likely a lost cause.)  Is there a reference list for these search codes?

Comment: The sort on the "Active" tab sorts by questions which have had edits, comments, or answers most recently. That should take care of your concern about ancient questions, since they'd be waaaaaay at the bottom of the "Active" tab.

Comment: Edited my answer to address your question